# Redirecting https://www to https://non-www

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, https

I have a secure wordpress website redirecting issue. I've researched this as thoroughly as I can, but can't seem to figure it out. I have two conditions for redirecting traffic in the .htaccess file. The first, is that all `http://www` traffic needs to be redirected to `https://afspa.org`. This I've accomplished with the following:

```
#BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://afspa.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

My second condition is that all `https://www` traffic needs to also be redirected to `https://afspa.org`. However, when users type in or have bookmarked "`https://www.afspa.org`" they don't get redirected. Instead they get a security warning. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A word of advice: you shouldn't edit WordPress' htaccess rules (the part between `#BEGIN WordPress` and `#END WordPress` because WP will overwrite it every time there's an update. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12708/rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-get-overwritten for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your certificate is valid for `afspa.org` but not for `www.afspa.org`. The browser checks the certificate before redirecting.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I thought that .htaccess was always first. You are correct, the certificate is only valid for afspa.org. SO if the browser checks the certificate before redirecting, there is no recourse to getting 'https://www.afspa.org' to 'https://afspa.org'?

Comment: The certificate must cover both domains, with and without www. GeoTrust calls this [UC/SAN](http://www.geotrust.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-san-uc/).

Comment: Is there no alternative to this, other than having to buy an additional certificate just to allow user's to redirect?  I'm having this same issue.